# Scaled Assets for Splash Screen in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, splash-screen, screen-resolution, appxmanifest

In appxmanifest file, there are five options for Splash screen : 620x300, 775x375, 930x450, 1240x600 and 2480x1200.

I have the following resolutions in my 15" laptop :

1366x768 (Recommended)

1360x768

1280x720

1280x600

1024x768

800x600

My question is, if I provide all five image in appxmanifest for Splash Screen, how those going to effect my laptop's different reolustion. I looked into MSDN blogs mentioning about some scale factor. I also noticed that, for each splash screen image, corresponds to a name like "SplashScreen.scale-100", "SplashScreen.scale-125", "SplashScreen.scale-150", "SplashScreen.scale-200" and "SplashScreen.scale-400"..

Actually it's a very beginning level question, but I am kind of puzzled up with all those

Comment: Your laptop has a 15" monitor with 1366x768 so lets say it will use all the 100 scale image. Those images will look good(nopixels). Now lets say it has 1920x1080 resolution. The Images will still look great even if you use the 70 scale. Now imagine 1920x1080 on a 32" screen. if you dont have scale 140 or 180 there it will use the 100. The images will look bad with pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You have one minute video which explain [Scaling and effective pixels in UWP apps](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Scaling-and-effective-pixels-in-UWP-apps). In addition, the Store picks the assets to download based in part of the DPI of the device. Only the assets that best match the device are downloaded. By the way, don't hesite to add a maximum of assets.

To help you, the following extension can generate the different size for you.

[UWP Tile Generator Extension for Visual Studio](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/15/uwp-tile-generator-extension-for-visual-studio/)